# How to add connectSDK libraries to android studio

Tags: live-connect-sdk

I am just trying to know how to add connectSDK to android studio so I can work with their classes in the program

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Gradle.build:

```
implementation('com.connectsdk:connect-sdk-android:1.6.0')
```